# Formula to calculate a side of triangle with given angle

Tags: circles, triangles

[image]

I have triangle like in the picture.

The known angles:

- **α** *(total angle of the I-J-K2 triangle)*
- **b** *(total angle of the I-P2-K2 and I-P1-K2 triangles)*

The known 3D points with X,Y,Z-coordinates:

- **I**
- **J**
- **K1** *(tangent intersection point)*
- **K2** *(center of the circle)*

All distances between these 4 points are known (for example lenght of I-J, J-K2 or r). Also the lenght  of **arc** from **I** to **J** is known.

P1 and P2 points are unknown. The P1 is located somewhere on the line from I to J. The P2 is somewhere on the arc of the circle.

**a** with 360' degrees would form a complete circle, where K2 is the center point.

**What is the formula to calculate the length of X (distance between I-P1)? Or how I could calculate P1's or P2's 3D coordinates?**

Comment: Is the arc part of a circle of radius $R$ centered at $K_2$, so that the distance between $K _2$ and $P_2$ is also $R$?

Comment: **The distance between K2-P2 is the same lenght as R.**


When **a** is 360' degrees, it forms a full circle, where **K2** is the center point.

But here the max **a** angle is always something below 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may assume $r=1$. If you dilate or contract the image by a factor of $r$, that will simultaneously bring the radius to $r$ and scale $x$ by $r$. So we can simplify things a little by solving for $x$ with $r=1$ and then multiplying the result by $r$ for the general case.

Using the Law of Cosines, with three triangles in the figure:

$$\begin{aligned}
\left(x+\overline{P_1J}\right)^2=x^2+\left(\overline{P_1J}\right)^2+2x\left(\overline{P_1J}\right)
&=2(1-\cos(\alpha))\\
x^2
&=1+\left(\overline{P_1K_2}\right)^2-2\overline{P_1K_2}\cos(\beta)\\
\left(\overline{P_1J}\right)^2
&=1+\left(\overline{P_1K_2}\right)^2-2\overline{P_1K_2}\cos(\alpha-\beta)\\
\end{aligned}$$

This gives a system of equations with three unknowns: $x$, $\overline{P_1K_2}$, and $\overline{P_1J}$. You could use algebra to solve for $x$ as follows.

The second and third equations can be used to eliminate $x$ and $\overline{P_1J}$ from the first, leaving:

$$2r^2+2\left(\overline{P_1K_2}\right)^2-2r\overline{P_1K_2}\left(\cos(\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)\right)\\+2\sqrt{\left(r^2+\left(\overline{P_1K_2}\right)^2-2r\overline{P_1K_2}\cos(\beta)\right)\left(r^2+\left(\overline{P_1K_2}\right)^2-2r\overline{P_1K_2}\cos(\alpha-\beta)\right)}\\=2r^2(1-\cos(\alpha))$$

After moving the terms not under the radical to the left and squaring both sides, this equation is quartic in $\overline{P_1K_2}$. That means that you could solve for $\overline{P_1K_2}$ using Cardano's quartic solution method (or maybe something simpler depending on the exact values of $r$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$.) From there, you would know $x$ using the second equation from the system above.

Comment: So I need to know **P1-K2** first, and then I can use the second equation from the top, to calculate the **X** length. **X** is really the only thing I need to know.

I'm sorry but I have no idea about Cardano's quartic solution. Could you edit the answer to include the final equation to solve **P1-K2**? I propably don't have the skills to make it into **'P1-K2 = "equation"'** form on my own.

About the values: **α** is always lesser than 360 degrees. **β** is always lesser than **α**. **r** is always greater than zero.

Comment: [Solving a quartic polynomial exactly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) is better done as a _process_ rather than with a formula, like the quadratic formula. If you did write down the formula for the general solution to a quartic equation, it would take [quite a lot of space](http://suhaimiramly.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/quartic.jpg).

Comment: The space is not a problem. I need to use the formula in software programming, and make a copy of it, so I can use to count the X in realtime. But I found another way around. I'll mark this as the answer.